# ngrok URL for a1111 (stable-diffusion) hangs and times out

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, ngrok, stable-diffusion

I'm running Stable-Diffusion on an Amazom SageMaker instance and am trying to get a1111 set up. The tutorial I followed (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IQj5Pofrt8) has it tunneling through Ngrok. When i run the startup script, everything returned indicates that the app is running at the provided URL, but when I request said URL in Chrome (from MacOS Sonoma), it angs for a minute then times out.

Here is the output from running the startup script (with my token removed):

```
(studiolab) studio-lab-user@default:~/sagemaker-studiolab-notebooks/stable-diffusion-webui$ python launch.py --listen --xformers --enable-insecure-extension-access --ngrok MY_NGROK_TOKEN
Python 3.9.16 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Feb  1 2023, 21:39:03) 
[GCC 11.3.0]
Version: v1.7.0
Commit hash: cf2772fab0af5573da775e7437e6acdca424f26e
Launching Web UI with arguments: --listen --xformers --enable-insecure-extension-access --ngrok MY_NGROK_TOKEN
Style database not found: /home/studio-lab-user/sagemaker-studiolab-notebooks/stable-diffusion-webui/styles.csv
ngrok authtoken detected, trying to connect...
ngrok connected to localhost:7860! URL: https://f38b-3-20-229-229.ngrok-free.app
You can use this link after the launch is complete.
Loading weights [6ce0161689] from /home/studio-lab-user/sagemaker-studiolab-notebooks/stable-diffusion-webui/models/Stable-diffusion/v1-5-pruned-emaonly.safetensors
Running on local URL:  http://0.0.0.0:7860
Creating model from config: /home/studio-lab-user/sagemaker-studiolab-notebooks/stable-diffusion-webui/configs/v1-inference.yaml

To create a public link, set `share=True` in `launch()`.
Startup time: 22.7s (prepare environment: 6.9s, import torch: 3.8s, import gradio: 1.9s, setup paths: 5.2s, initialize shared: 0.5s, other imports: 1.5s, setup codeformer: 0.2s, load scripts: 0.7s, create ui: 0.8s, gradio launch: 1.1s).
Applying attention optimization: xformers... done.
Model loaded in 34.0s (load weights from disk: 1.6s, create model: 0.5s, apply weights to model: 31.1s, calculate empty prompt: 0.4s).
```

The dude in the tutorial got it to run fine by going to his equivalent of `https://f38b-3-20-229-229.ngrok-free.app`(from the output above) in a browser. As i said, mine hangs and then gives the "This site can't be reached ERR_TIMED_OUT" screen.

If you try that URL now, it definitely won't work as that session is no longer active... but that's what was happening. I'm happy to post the code from the startup script, but it doesn't seem like there's any problem there... but let me know if you want to see it anyway.

HAs anyone run into this? or have any idea what the issue may be?

Comment: It ended up being an issue on my LAN. My ISPs firmware was blocking the domain, ngrok-free.app. I whitelisted and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely a network configuration issue. To isolate the cause of the problem, please try to test Ngrok with a simpler website (such as python3 -m http.server 9000), and check it works.